# PHP + MySQL: How much programming can or should I include within a db transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, transactions

How much PHP code can / should I include within a single MySQL transaction?  What is the best practice for transactions in terms of calling other classes & methods, manipulating or creating instances, etc, within a single transaction?

What I mean here by "include" is enter between `beginTransaction();` and `commit();`

Comment: Don't think about "code in the transaction", think about controlling the *lifetime* of a transaction. Generally, this lifetime should be the *smallest required to **safely** and **efficiently** complete the operation* but there is no hard rule: it depends. Transactions can maintain locks on database resources. This can be good (ACID). And bad (contention). I generally design code such that transactions are *only* "passed down" the call-stack and *never* stored in an object as it makes lifetime tracking much simpler.

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence please?

Comment: I never assign a transaction to an instance variable. So the scope (function) that creates the transaction must also ultimately cleanup the transaction. If other functions needs access to the transaction then it is passed through parameters. Any function passed a transaction is *not* the owner and must *not* interfere with the lifetime (save for later, cleanup abnormally, etc). Thus I know the a transaction is always complete (committed or rolled back and disposed) when the function that first created the transaction ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am used to use one transaction for one element and all its dependencies.

For example, I have a forum where users can change their nickname. But they also can remove their account and I do not want to see posts removed. So I need to save somewhere in each post the name of my user in a `VARCHAR` or such.

If a user changes his nickname, I will begin a transaction, changes his nickname everywhere it could be and if there were no errors, so I commit. I do not look at the number of requests at this point, because if one request fails I should be able to rollback everything regarding this change.

But in a case that an admin changes 2 nicknames in an admin panel and validate once, I will open 2 transactions (one per user) to avoid having troubles with a single transaction.